# How to skip a column level in a multi index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a nested multi-index dataframe with 3 levels and I want to select the 1st and 3rd level without selecting the 2nd level. Is it possible to do that?

My current code looks like this (updated). now I am getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' for panda which I am not sure why. 'D' and 'E' are the columns that I want to select from the 3rd level.

```
   df1_1 = data['A'].loc['B',:,'D','E']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a sample dataframe from [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers)  You can use `loc` with `axis` parameter or slicers or IndexSlice:

Setup:

```
def mklbl(prefix,n):
    return ["%s%s" % (prefix,i)  for i in range(n)]

miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([mklbl('A',4),
                                        mklbl('B',2),
                                      mklbl('C',4),
                                       mklbl('D',2)])

micolumns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a','foo'),('a','bar'),
                                        ('b','foo'),('b','bah')],
                                       names=['lvl0', 'lvl1'])


dfmi = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(len(miindex)*len(micolumns)).reshape((len(miindex),len(micolumns))),
                    index=miindex,
                     columns=micolumns).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)


dfmiT = dfmi.T.copy()

dfmiT
```

Input dataframe:

```
          A0                                    ...    A3                      \
          B0                             B1     ...    B0        B1             
          C0     C1      C2      C3      C0     ...    C3        C0        C1   
          D0 D1  D0  D1  D0  D1  D0  D1  D0  D1 ...    D0   D1   D0   D1   D0   
lvl0 lvl1                                       ...                             
a    bar   1  5   9  13  17  21  25  29  33  37 ...   217  221  225  229  233   
     foo   0  4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36 ...   216  220  224  228  232   
b    bah   3  7  11  15  19  23  27  31  35  39 ...   219  223  227  231  235   
     foo   2  6  10  14  18  22  26  30  34  38 ...   218  222  226  230  234
```

Let's use `.loc` with `axis` parameter:

```
dfmiT.loc(axis=1)['A3',:,'C2']
```

Output:

```
            A3               
            B0        B1     
            C2        C2     
            D0   D1   D0   D1
lvl0 lvl1                    
a    bar   209  213  241  245
     foo   208  212  240  244
b    bah   211  215  243  247
     foo   210  214  242  246
```

Comment: I would include a `pd.IndexSlice` example, such as `dfmi.loc['a', pd.IndexSlice['A2',:,'C1']]`. This is usually my preferred method for slicing MultiIndex dataframes.

Comment: yes im trying all these approaches but i used axis = 0 maybe that caused the problem. and because this is a nested dataframe that looks like what you have above, I am first calling the main column 'A' from the main dataframe - data['A'].loc .. but thanks a lot for these suggestions. i will try it and update.

Comment: Is your MultiIndex in column headers or the dataframe Index?

Comment: i don't quite understand the question but i have a dataframe with multiple columns and in one of these columns there is this nested dataframe that it multiindexed like what you showed above.